# Fedora: Error when install Postgres SQL: nothing provides libicui18n.so.69()

Tags: fedora, repository, dnf, postgresql

I had installed the Postgresql database on my Fedora system, which worked without problems.
After some time I had uninstalled Postgres and wanted to reinstall it.
When reinstalling with the following command:

```
sudo dnf install postgresql postgresql-server
```

, the following error message appears:

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requirements
  - nothing provides libicui18n.so.69()(64bit) required by postgresql-server-13.7-2.module_f37+14770+1ab93350.x86_64
  - nothing provides libicuuc.so.69()(64bit) required by postgresql-server-13.7-2.module_f37+14770+1ab93350.x86_64
```

Can anyone help me with this error message?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using third party repos which makes answering your question quite difficult. Maybe you could disable or remove them.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Which command should I use for this?

Comment: Google: `dnf disable repo` Google: `dnf list repos`